# How to fetch data-attr outside a div where event is happening jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using owl slider and i have multiple sliders on one page for each video category. So I have added each category slug in a div. Now on `owl-next` click i want to fetch `data-slug` for the clicked category. Here is what i tried but it just fetches the **first** category not others.

> **Note:** If you have in mind that why not adding the data-categoryslug inside owl-next div so owl carousel does these
>   things on initializatio i have no idea how to add it in there.

js:

// Get Next Videos for Owl Carousal

```
        $('.blog-groups .blog-slider .owl-nav .owl-next').click(function(e){
            var categorySlug = $('.ajax-cate').data('categoryslug');
            console.log(categorySlug);
         });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blog-groups">
    <div class="group-heading">

        <div class="blog-slider owl-lg-dot mb-none owl-theme owl-loaded owl-carousel owl-carousel-init" id="videoList">

            <div class="owl-controls">
                <div class="owl-nav">
                    <div class="owl-prev" style="display: block;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="owl-next" style=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="group-seemore">
            <a class="ajax-cate" data-categoryslug="slug-is-here" href="/blog/category/slug-is-here" title="">
                See more
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to get all sliders and add $(this), this will select the clicked one

Comment: `// Get Next Videos for Owl Carousal
        $('.blog-category-items .blog-slider .owl-next').click(function(e){
            console.log($(this).closest('.group-heading').find('.cate-ajax').data('slug'));
            console.log($(this).closest('.ajax-cate').data('categoryslug'));
            console.log($(this).closest('.ajax-cate').attr('data-categoryslug'));` I tried all these but getting null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code. You need to relate the element which you are trying to get to your clicked element by using `$(this)` and then `parents()` to go above to the parent tag and then at last use `find()`.

```
$('.owl-next').on('click', function() { 
    var categorySlug = $(this).parents('.blog-groups').find('.ajax-cate').data('categoryslug');
    console.log(categorySlug);
});
```

Comment: Vimeo Not loading if any possible to play vimeo Videos

Comment: @CreativeEnemy: Post a question for the issue.